# Retrieving Individual Columns from an ADO.NET Result Set

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a website which is set to query a database for a username, and then populate the `Session[]` variables with the user's info.  When I query using the server's stored procedure, I get back the entire row.  How can I split apart the row and parse it so that every column gets parsed separately?

My code for the button is:

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strConn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TicketsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConn);
    //Search button
    string sqlText = ("select * from [dbo].[User]");






    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlText,myConnection);
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataReader objReader;
    objReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    objGrid.DataSource = objReader;
    objGrid.DataBind();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I updated it to `string sqlText = ("select 'UserID', 'FirstName' from [dbo].[User] where UserID='"+txtTest.Text+"' and Password='" + txtPass.Text+"'");`

But now I get the following column 
Column1 Column2
 UserID FirstName

Comment: there are many ways to query a database using ASP.net, so you will have to add more detail and probably some code before you get anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To read a column's value use this:

```
 avar = row["colname"];
```

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with the query in the example, and you are using databind so you don't need to access a row.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
string sqlText = ("select * from [dbo].[User]");
```

Use:

```
 string sqlText = ("select username from [dbo].[User]");
```

That will return just the column you need.

*** UPDATE ***

Making a series of queries for all the properties is definitely not a good option. You can select all the columns you need by separating by comma like this:

```
 string sqlText = ("select username, otherfield, evenAnotherField from [dbo].[User]");
```

Then you can use the [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w9y9ttex.aspx) [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy.aspx) to get the values you need:

```
  var username = objReader["username"];
```

Comment: The problem is that I have about 8 different session variables which must be populated.  Should I just use 8 different queries or is there an easier way?

Comment: I updated it to 
string sqlText = ("select 'UserID', 'FirstName' from [dbo].[User] where UserID='"+txtTest.Text+"' and Password='" + txtPass.Text+"'");

But now I get the following column
  Column1 Column2
 UserID FirstName